# Error "Image source URL is missing" use ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, kcfinder

Error **"Image source URL is missing"** when upload image use ckeditor.How to config it

Comment: Are you using ckfinder, kcfinder, or another file browser with ckeditor  to upload images?

Comment: have you solve it ?

Comment: Hey did you find any solution for this

Comment: * I still haven't found a solution